# tikz/pgfplots ignores last column for coloring

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using the following tex script from a software suite, producing parts of a bigger plot. It works more or less like expected, but there is one problem.
As I am not a regular user of PGF/TikZ I am struggeling to find the error.

This is the essential part of the code giving the image below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations, plotmarks, fit, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}

\begin{filecontents}{all.data}
    Header
    1    1SingNA  1.44700  0.05000
    2    2SingNA  1.56100  0.00000
    3    3SingNA  1.88500  0.23100
    4    4SingNA  2.06700  0.10800
    5    5SingNA  2.11000  0.20900
    6    6SingNA  2.18400  0.00300
    7    7SingNA  2.25500  0.04600
    8    8SingNA  2.29000  0.00000
    9    9SingNA  2.46900  0.21800
    10   10SingNA  2.50100  0.46700
    11   11SingNA  2.54300  0.00000
    12   12SingNA  2.62500  0.01000
    13   13SingNA  2.86200  0.13100
    14   14SingNA  2.92100  0.27300
\end{filecontents}

% settings for the coordinate system
\pgfplotsset{
    every linear axis/.append style={
        width=8.500 cm, height=2.0cm,xmin=0, xmax=15,
        scale only axis, axis on top,
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1},
        legend style={at={(1.01,0.00)}, anchor=south west, draw=none, fill=black!5, inner sep=0.5pt, outer sep=0.5pt},
        legend columns=1, legend cell align=left},
}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={CI}{color=(black); color=(blue!50); color=(green!70);}}

% ===========================================================================

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        anchor=south west, at={(0,0)},
        height=3.0cm,
        xlabel={}, ylabel={Energy (eV)},
        xtick={-10}, xticklabels={},
        colorbar % uncomment for colorbar as legend
        ]
        \addplot[mark=-, only marks, mark options={scale=2, line width=2pt}]  table[x index=0, y index=2] {all.data};

        \addplot+[solid, mesh, point meta=explicit, no markers, line width=5cm, shader=flat corner] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}-0.5, y expr=2, meta index=3, meta expr=\thisrowno{3}] {all.data};
        % LABELING THE ACTUAL NUMBERS TO SHOW THAT THE COLUMN AT LEAST IS THERE
        \addplot+[ybar, nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic, no markers, xticklabel style={rotate=90}] table[x index=0, y index=3, meta index=3, meta expr=\thisrowno{3}] {all.data};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### What I get:

[image: image from code example with last column colored white instead of blue]

The bars for each column are colored according to a value in an external file but the last column does not get colored.

### What I would like to have:

I also would like to have this last column to get colored according to its value from the external file.

Comment: Welcome! Would you mind explaining a bit more the purpose of `line width=5cm`? And/or explain more abstractly what you want to achieve?  (Also `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}` is a bit outdated, we are now at `1.17`.)

Comment: This is only a part of a bigger image, so the `line width` and probably some other commands are probably not necessary here, but for the full picture. As I said, I want the script to also color the last (most right) column in the image according to the value from the file (0.273), which should be blueish like the 9th column. I could explain it in chat, if you have more questions.

Comment: As far as I understood it, `x expr` does only change the placing. I think the columns are placed well, as the green column is the one with the highest value. The problem is, that the 14th column doesn't get colored but it actually should.

Comment: I’m very happy that you seem to be interested and I want to explain it as good as I can. Would you mind, let me explain it in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107490/discussion-by-ph13-yet-another-philipp) to you?

Comment: I don’t insist on anything. I just thought, it is something simple that I’ve overseen that would fix my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107491/discussion-between-ph13-yet-another-philipp-and-schrodingers-cat).

Comment: See if you like `\addplot[scatter,mark=square*, point meta=explicit,only marks,
   mark size=0.28cm,
   mark options={yscale=8}] 
   table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y expr=1.5, 
 meta index=3] {all.data};` better. Add `clip marker paths` to the options of the axis.

Comment: Yes, that is doing the job very well. Do you mind writing a short answer, that I can accept?

Comment: I will be happy to write an answer but at this point I am not yet fully convinced by the output. For instance, the `nodes near coords` are overlapping. Do you intend to keep them like this? (I also think that a cleaner solution may be to put two `axis` environments on top where one draws the "bars" as a 3d mesh plot but with `view={90}{0}`, but I did not try this out.)

Comment: The plot with `nodes near coord` are not in the final image. I just included them to highlight for me, that the numbers are actually read from my input, but just not converted into a color for the right most column (aka the last row in `all.data`).

Comment: I changed your code to be `\addplot[scatter,mark=square*, point meta=explicit,only marks, mark size=0.26cm, mark options={yscale=8}] table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y expr=2, meta index=3] {all.data};` and changed the surrounding code to fit nicely to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically an extended comment. The message is that there might be better ways than using a 1D mesh plot with a huge line width to achieve your goal. Examples include a 3d mesh plot viewed "from the top" or (ab)use plot marks to get these bars. This is an example, with the understanding that this is not the final plot. (I adapted the [version from your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541831/tikz-pgfplots-ignores-last-column-for-coloring/541836#comment1368607_541831) since this seems to be closer to what you want.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{filecontents}{all.data}
    Header
    1    1SingNA  1.44700  0.05000
    2    2SingNA  1.56100  0.00000
    3    3SingNA  1.88500  0.23100
    4    4SingNA  2.06700  0.10800
    5    5SingNA  2.11000  0.20900
    6    6SingNA  2.18400  0.00300
    7    7SingNA  2.25500  0.04600
    8    8SingNA  2.29000  0.00000
    9    9SingNA  2.46900  0.21800
    10   10SingNA  2.50100  0.46700
    11   11SingNA  2.54300  0.00000
    12   12SingNA  2.62500  0.01000
    13   13SingNA  2.86200  0.13100
    14   14SingNA  2.92100  0.27300
\end{filecontents}

% settings for the coordinate system
\pgfplotsset{
    every linear axis/.append style={
        width=8.500 cm, height=2.0cm,xmin=0, xmax=15,
        scale only axis, axis on top,
        yticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=1},
        legend style={at={(1.01,0.00)}, anchor=south west, draw=none, fill=black!5, inner sep=0.5pt, outer sep=0.5pt},
        legend columns=1, legend cell align=left},
}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={CI}{color=(black); color=(blue!50); color=(green!70);}}

% ===========================================================================

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[clip marker paths,
    anchor=south west, at={(0,0)},
    height=3.0cm,
    xlabel={}, ylabel={Energy (eV)},
    xtick={-10}, xticklabels={},
    colorbar, % uncomment for colorbar as legend
    nodes near coords
    style={font=\footnotesize,text=white,rotate=90,anchor=west}
    ]
   \addplot[mark=-, only marks, mark options={scale=2, line width=2pt}]  table[x index=0, y index=2] {all.data};
% 
   \addplot[scatter,mark=square*, point meta=explicit,only marks, mark
        size=0.265cm, mark options={yscale=8}] table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y expr=2, meta
        index=3] {all.data};    
% LABELING THE ACTUAL NUMBERS TO SHOW THAT THE COLUMN AT LEAST IS THERE
  \addplot[ybar, nodes near coords, 
  %point meta=explicit symbolic, 
  no markers, xticklabel style={rotate=90}] 
  table[x index=0, y index=3, meta index=3] {all.data}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]